# SQL return data where low score is less than average low score?

Tags: sql, group-by, having

I have a question on a homework assignment where I need to list the quiz number and date of those quizzes that have a low score less than the average low score.

To do this I need to use a GROUP BY clause and a HAVING clause. It should look something like this:

```
select quiznum, quizdate
from quizzes
group by quiznum, quizdate, lowscore 
having lowscore < avg(lowscore);
```

This however returns no data found.

If I put the average score in manually (which is approximately 14) it retruns the information I need, but in regards to the question I do not know the average lowscore.

How do I list the quiz number and date in which the low score is less than the average low score?

Comment: Hint:  You need a subquery in the `HAVING` clause and no aggregation in the outer query.

Comment: Post DDL with sample data and desired output

Comment: What does the assignment consider a 'lowscore'?  Is there a 'Score' column in the quizzes table?  Are you needing to first find the low scores or does this table simply contain a column named 'lowscore' and you are simply needing to find scores lower than the average of the values in the lowscore column?  Please explain as these pieces of the puzzle are important if one is to assist you with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this query might be work for you.

You need to create a subquery to get `avg` score.Then `join` self and compare it.

```
SELECT T2.* 
FROM 
(
    SELECT quiznum, 
       quizdate,
       avg(lowscore) as avgScore
    FROM quizzes
    group by quiznum, quizdate
) T1 INNER JOIN quizzes T2 
ON 
    T1.quiznum = T2.quiznum 
AND 
    T1.quizdate = T2.quizdate
Where T2.lowscore < T1.avgScore
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I find it easier to work with Analytical Windowing Functions to accomplish the desired output.  The Key that gets me the desired output in my query is:

`AVG(score) OVER (PARTITION BY quiznum, quizdate) AS avg_score`

The Query that makes this work is below.  I'm using a WITH Clause to create the fake data but don't let that confuse you.  The BASE query is what you are needing.  The WITH Clause is simply here to create a fake table with data to work with.

```
WITH demo_data AS
(
  SELECT    1001     AS quiznum,    '10-JAN-18'  AS quizdate,   91   AS score    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT    1001     AS quiznum,    '10-JAN-18'  AS quizdate,   75   AS score    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT    1001     AS quiznum,    '10-JAN-18'  AS quizdate,   35   AS score    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT    1001     AS quiznum,    '10-JAN-18'  AS quizdate,   40   AS score    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT    1001     AS quiznum,    '10-JAN-18'  AS quizdate,   70   AS score    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT    1001     AS quiznum,    '10-JAN-18'  AS quizdate,   85   AS score    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT    1002     AS quiznum,    '17-JAN-18'  AS quizdate,   35   AS score    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT    1002     AS quiznum,    '17-JAN-18'  AS quizdate,   40   AS score    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT    1002     AS quiznum,    '17-JAN-18'  AS quizdate,   70   AS score    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT    1002     AS quiznum,    '17-JAN-18'  AS quizdate,   85   AS score    FROM dual
)
SELECT quiznum, quizdate, score, avg_score
FROM
(
  SELECT quiznum, quizdate, score, AVG(score) OVER (PARTITION BY quiznum, quizdate) AS avg_score
  FROM demo_data
)
WHERE score < avg_score
;
```

The image below shows ALL of the Data by quiz number and date and tells us the Average Score.  We can use this by wrapping it with an outer Select so we can then add a Filter in the WHERE clause in order to compare the Score with the Average Score.

[image]

The next image shows what it looks like after adding the Filter in the WHERE Clause:

[image]